# No JavaScript syntax highlighting in Eclipse 2020-09

Tags: eclipse

I just upgraded to Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17.0) from Eclipse Luna. After installing, I installed Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.19 from the Marketplace, then restarted Eclipse. When I open a .js file, there is no syntax highlighting. It was fine out of the box with Luna, so is there anything extra that I need to configure in 2020-09? File associations for *.js shows this:

[image]

Comment: Does right-clicking the file and choosing _Open With > Generic Text Editor_ work?

Comment: @howlger I tried this and it worked! That made me realize *.js was associated with another editor by default that didn't have the syntax highlighting. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems JavaScript files (`*.js`) have been associated with the plain **text editor instead of** the ***Generic Text Editor*** by mistake (please make sure it has been reported to Eclipse).

**Right-click** the file and choose ***Open With > Generic Text Editor***.

Or better, associate all `*.js` files with the *Generic Text Editor* by **right-click a `*.js` file**, choose ***Open With > Other...***, **select the *Generic Text Editor*** in the list and tick the ***Use it for all '*.js' files*** checkbox at the bottom ([as shown in my video here](https://youtu.be/V5O52H7e8oc?t=614)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install the Wild Web Developer feature so that it provides that functionality through the Generic Text Editor.

Comment: Wild Web Developer + _Generic_ Text Editor (not "Text Editor") worked for me. Using just one or the other did not work... I needed to use both.